# Vim S&R to remove number from end of InstallShield file

Tags: regex, vim

I've got a practical application for a vim regex where I'd like to remove numbers from the end of file location links.  For example, if the developer is sloppy and just adds files and doesn't reuse file locations, you'll end up with something awful like this:

```
PATH_TO_MY_FILES&gt
PATH_TO_MY_FILES1&gt
...
PATH_TO_MY_FILES22&gt
PATH_TO_MY_FILES_ELSEWHERE&gt
PATH_TO_MY_FILES_ELSEWHERE1&gt
...
```

So all I want to do is to S&R and replace PATH_TO_MY_FILES*\d+ with PATH_TO_MY_FILES* using regex.  Obviously I am not doing it quite right, so I was hoping someone here could not spoon feed the answer necessarily, but throw a regex buzzword my way to get me on track.

Here's what I have tried:

```
:%s\(PATH_TO_MY_FILES\w*\)\(\d+\)&gt:gc
```

But this doesn't work, i.e. if I just do a vim search on that, it doesn't find anything.  However, if I use this:

```
:%s\(PATH_TO_MY_FILES\w*\)\(\d\)&gt:gc
```

It will match the string, but the grouping is off, as expected.  For example, the string PATH_TO_MY_FILES22 will be grouped as (PATH_TO_MY_FILES2)(2), presumably because the \d only matches the 2, and the \w match includes the first 2.

**Question 1: Why doesn't \d+ work?**

If I go ahead and use the second string (which is wrong), Vim appears to find a match (even though the grouping is wrong), but then does the replacement incorrectly.

For example, given that we know the \d will only match the last number in the string, I would expect `PATH_TO_MY_FILES22&gt` to get replaced with `PATH_TO_MY_FILES2&gt`.  However, instead it replaces it with this:

PATH_TO_MY_FILES2PATH_TO_MY_FILES22&gtgt

So basically, it looks like it finds PATH_TO_MY_FILES22&gt, but then replaces only the & with group 1, which is PATH_TO_MY_FILES2.

I tried another regex at Regexr.com to see how it would interpret my grouping, and it looked correct, but maybe a hack around my lack of regex understanding:

(PATH_TO_\D*)(\d*)&gt

This correctly broke my target string into the PATH part and the entire number, so I was happy.  But then when I used this in Vim, it found the match, but still replaced only the &.

**Question 2: Why is Vim only replacing the &?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

You need to escape the `+` or it will be taken literally.  For example `\d\+` works correctly.

**Answer 2:**

An unescaped `&` in the replacement portion of a substitution means "the entire matched text".  You need to escape it if you want a literal ampersand.

Comment: See also `:h \v` for info on how to make Vim's regex engine more like common regex/PCRE.

Comment: oh man...  :)  Thanks, I'll try this now.  Funny (or not) how missing \ screws everything up.  But I was completely unaware of how & behaves when unescaped in the replacement string.  Thanks!